# How to group and order dependent results by dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery, grouping

I have a database of units which have expiry dates. Some of the units are top level units and have sub-assemblies attached. Sub-assemblies also have expiry dates. I'm trying to create a listing that lists the top-level units ordered by their expiration dates and list all relevant sub-assemblies under them.

The ordering should be done in two different ways:

1. Query which lists top-level units and their sub-assemblies according to expiry date of the parent item.
2. Query which lists top-level units and their sub-assemblies ordered by the first expiry date of relevant sub-assembly under them.

Here's example of the master table:

```
    ITEM   | NAME             | UID | INSTALLED_TO_UID | EXPIRY  
    AAA    | Top_level_unit_1 | 1   |                  | 2018-03-06  
    BBB    | Sub_assy_1       | 75  | 1                | 2019-06-11  
    AAA    | Top_level_unit_2 | 2   |                  | 2018-08-12  
    CCC    | Sub_assy_2       | 26  | 1                | 2020-02-05  
    DDD    | Sub_assy_3       | 59  | 2                | 2019-11-11  
    EEE    | Sub_assy_4       | 41  | 2                | 2019-10-30  
    FFF    | Sub_assy_5       | 11  | 1                | 2018-04-10
```

I am running these now in nested queries (second query inside foreach loop), but i am sure there is better and more efficient way of doing this. At least for case 1.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM master 
 WHERE ITEM = AAA 
 ORDER 
    BY EXPIRY ASC
```

And inside result loop for each result:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM master 
 WHERE INSTALLED_TO_UID = (UID from parent query)
```

The result should be like:

```
    ITEM   | NAME             | UID | INSTALLED_TO_UID | EXPIRY  
    AAA    | Top_level_unit_1 | 1   |                  | 2018-03-06  
    BBB    | Sub_assy_1       | 75  | 1                | 2019-06-11  
    CCC    | Sub_assy_2       | 26  | 1                | 2020-02-05 
    FFF    | Sub_assy_5       | 11  | 1                | 2018-04-10
    AAA    | Top_level_unit_2 | 2   |                  | 2018-08-12   
    DDD    | Sub_assy_3       | 59  | 2                | 2019-11-11  
    EEE    | Sub_assy_4       | 41  | 2                | 2019-10-30
```

For case 2 i don't have a clue yet...

Summary: I would like to have only one query to group and order the results instead of relying to another query in result loop. Secondly i would like to figure out a query to order the results by first expiring child item grouped by parent items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an outer self join to find the parent record (for query 1) or the first-of-children record (for query 2). Then you can use `coalesce` to decide which value to take (either from the joined table or the main one) for setting the order.

Query 1:

```
SELECT    record.* 
FROM      master record
LEFT JOIN master parent
       ON record.installed_to_uid = parent.uid
      AND parent.installed_to_uid is null
ORDER BY  COALESCE(parent.expiry, record.expiry),
          COALESCE(parent.uid, record.uid),
          COALESCE(record.installed_to_uid,-1),
          record.expiry
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT    record.* 
FROM      master record
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   installed_to_uid, MIN(expiry) expiry
           FROM     master
           WHERE    installed_to_uid IS NOT NULL
           GROUP BY installed_to_uid) first
       ON COALESCE(record.installed_to_uid, record.uid) = first.installed_to_uid
ORDER BY  COALESCE(first.expiry, record.expiry),
          COALESCE(first.installed_to_uid, record.uid),
          COALESCE(record.installed_to_uid,-1),
          record.expiry
```

See it run on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/499d18/3)

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be quite close here, but there are few oddities with results. With query 1 i get 5000+ results although there are only 1400 rows in database. The query lists the results correctly, childs nested below parents, but also creates multiple other occurrencies without the parent.

Comment: The first query can only return more records than you have in the table when `uid` is not unique, otherwise the `left join` never increases the number of records already selected from  `master`. Can you provide a set of data for which you have such behaviour, so I could have a look at it?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. The UID is unique to ITEM only. See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f32d16/2 I could add unique ID column though.

Comment: So the uid is not uid (universal unique identifier). So you are saying the primary key is a composite: item + uid? This is confusing...  Can you confirm?

Comment: Anyway, I have updated the first query to include an extra join condition to make sure only records are joined that have `parent.installed_to_uid is null`

Comment: Sorry, i simplified the example a bit too much. The UID column was named mistakenly UID in example, should be UNIT_ID. It is unique only to each item. There is also a ID field in table which is a primary key. But the items are linked together by UNIT_ID and INSTALLED_TO. This i can't change. I updated the table structure in SQLfiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd2b03

Answer (score 0):

Although there are surely more efficient solutions, why not start with this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM master 
 WHERE INSTALLED_TO_UID = (

SELECT UID
  FROM master 
 WHERE ITEM = AAA

)
```

?